# FormatMessage() pauses the program when dwMessageId = 35, 37, 40... etc

Tags: c++, winapi

I was playing with C++ again when I found this problem. I want to list all errors when I met `GetLastError();`. I found that it only gives the error code and so it is when I've met `FormatMessage();`. Everything goes smoothly and until `DWORD en` reaches 35.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

void psdem(DWORD en) {
    LPVOID error;
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        en,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&error,
        0,
        NULL);
    cout << (LPCTSTR)error;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0 ; ((i <= 2147483647) & (i >= 0)) ; i++) {
        psdem(i);
        cout << endl;
    }
    getch();
}
```

It is confusing and I am stuck with it. I believe there IS a solution to fix it but I've searched for the solution via the Internet but I just can't find the solution.

So, I then coded to skip 35 and then here comes 37 who causes the program to stuck. Again, I coded to skip it and 40 comes to place. Then, I realized that it is not an individual error.

> Why is this happening and how can I fix that?

Comment: There's no `cout` in c language, such this question is definitely about c++, also `FormatMessage()` is a winapi function and not standard c++, hence I've added the appropriate tag.

Comment: Oops, sorry, tagged wrongly. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Heads-up: the condition of your `for` is always true and leads to signed integer oveflow if `int` is 32-bit.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks. Nearly missed that.

Comment: There is no message with code 35, 37, 40 and so on. `error` is null on these codes, and `cout` errors on outputting a `(LPCTSTR)0`. Check the return value of `FormatMessage` before using the output parameters.

Comment: who will be free `error` memory ? you forget call `LocalFree(error)`. and you not check result of `FormatMessage`

Comment: and paused not `FormatMessage`. possible `cout`

Comment: @GSerg I think your reply is good enough to be an answer. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @RbMm Ooh, I didn't even know I'd need to `free` that. New thing to me.
BTW, does that causes memory leak?

Comment: of course this cause memory leak, in your case huge (because you leak many time). and not `free` (this is error) by `LocalFree` - [*The caller should use the `LocalFree` function to free the buffer when it is no longer needed.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage)

Comment: When you use a new Win32 API function, **you should always read the documentation** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage.

Comment: Wow... Seems there's a serious problem in my code...
Thanks for helping me out to prevent the disastrous consequence...

Comment: @Phil1970 I've read about it, but not fully read. (Oops.